# Modify gtk3 theme - menu bar

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk3

I've installed **FaienceZukiMac** gtk3 theme and there's a "white balloon" surrounding each entry in the menu of every gtk3 program.

Here's a screenshot of what I'm talking about

[image: Screenshot]

How can I change it in order to remove that "white balloon" and make it the same color as the general background?

I was messing with the color values of the gtk-main.css with no luck. Also, I don't know the "real" name of that area of the window. Is it called menu bar?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

.menubar .menuitem {
background-color: inherit;
backround-image: none}
would fix the problem i think